# Android viewing image using Intent.ACTION_VIEW closes current activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using this code to open an image using default android image viewer:

```
Intent intentquick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentquick.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
startActivity(intentquick);
```

On some devices, when pressing back key after viewing the image, it returns to the previous activity as intended, while on other devices, `onDestroy` is invoked and the application closes.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Device`s memory difference is possible problem.
The previous activity is in Stopped state.So it will be killed in low system memory.